# python log parse create dict of repetitive url and size with count

Tags: python, parsing, logging, dictionary

I want to parse log file from below format, there are multiple urls are repetitive and I want to compute total size of each and every urls as well as compute the size of particular type of urls, what would be the best way?

```
/images/img81a.jpg 6620
/images/img88a.jpg 6990
/images/img80b.jpg 5909 
/images/swb-30-furniture.gif 6216 
/images/button-arrow.png 498
/images/button-arrow-down.png 484 
/images/img81a.jpg 6620 
/images/img80b.jpg 5909 
/images/back-to-top_off.gif 1506 
/images/new-logo.gif 3377 
/images/img81a.jpg 6620        

Result:

Total size computation: 11503
```

All particular type of urls size computation:

```
 /images/img81a.jpg 19860
 /images/img80b.jpg 11818
 like wise ...
```

I append all size values to list and perform addition to get the total size result, but for similar kind of urls size computation requires two dimension dict, I guess. Which I am not about to create.

```
 a['/images/img81a.jpg'][6620] = 3
 a['/images/img88a.jpg'][6990] = 1
 a['/images/img80b.jpg'][5909] = 2
 like wise ...
```

Comment: And the code you've got so far reads as... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have all your lines in a list:

```
with open('log.txt') as f:
    dico = dict()
    total_value = 0
    for line in f:
        #Feeding the dictionary
        split_array = line.split()
        possible_key = split_array[0]
        value = int(split_array[1])

        #If url has already been processed, update the value
        #Else, initialize the entry in the dictionary => default=0
        dico[possible_key] = dico.get(possible_key, default=0) + value

        #Updating the global sum
        total_value = total_value + value
```

Usage:

```
dico['/images/img81a.jpg'] => 19860
```

Comment: A workable solution.  Some suggestions:  (0) use a `with` statement to open the file: `with open('log.txt') as f:`  (1) don't use `file.readlines()`, all you are doing is handling input lines one at a time, and you can just do `for line in f:` under the `with` statement (you will get one line at a time and memory use will be much lower) (2) you can just call `line.split()` and it will split on any white space (3) don't call `line.split()` twice; just split the line and then collect `possible_key` and `value` from the split results (4) look into `defaultdict` from the `Collections` module.

Comment: `if possible_key in dico.keys():
    dico[possible_key] = dico[possible_key] + value
else:
    dico[possible_key] = value`
could be replaced with: `dico[possible_key] = dico.get(possible_key, 0) + value`